# Get symbolic expression from residue result

Tags: matlab

Using the residue function, I get the result as some vector variables:

[r,p,k] = residue(b,a)

Is there any way to build a symbolic expression (on the variable of my choice, e.g. 'x') from the return result, like:

```
eq = residue2sym(r,p,k)
pretty(eq)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I implemented it myself:

```
function eq = residue2sym( R,P,K )

syms s

eq = 0;

lastR = NaN;
lastP = NaN;
multiplicityCounter = 1;
for i = 1:length(R)
    rc = R(i);
    pc = P(i);

    if(~isnan(lastP) )
        if(pc == lastP && abs(lastR) < 1e-15)   % Quando existe multiplicidade, o R correspondente ao primeiro P
                                                % da multiplicidade deveria
                                                % ser 0, mas estranhamente
                                                % aparece como -4.4409e-16.
                                                % O que deveria ser uma
                                                % comparação com 0 então
                                                % vira uma comparação para
                                                % um módulo bem pequeno
            multiplicityCounter = multiplicityCounter + 1;
        else
            eq = eq + lastR/(s - lastP)^multiplicityCounter;
            multiplicityCounter = 1;
        end
    end
    lastR = rc;
    lastP = pc;
end
if(~isnan(lastP))
    eq = eq + lastR/(s - lastP)^multiplicityCounter;
end

 if(~isempty(K))
     eq = eq + sum(s.^(0:length(K)));
 end

eq = vpa( eq, 2);

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function [F, r, p, k] = residue2sym(b, a)
    [r, p, k] = residue(b, a);
    syms s;
    repeat = ones(size(p));
    for i = 2:length(p)
        if p(i) == p(i-1)
            repeat(i) = repeat(i-1) + 1;
        end
    end
    F = sum(r./(s-p).^repeat) + poly2sym(k, s);
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).